How can I add private nameservers to my Hestia Control Panel setup on Google Cloud?
I currently have Hestia Control Panel up and running on a Google Compute Engine VM using Cloud Flare (free plan) with my domain registered at NameCheap. I have about a dozen clients on a reseller plan elsewhere that I want to migrate to this VM, but I would like to run my own nameservers on multiple IP addresses for better resiliency and branding.
I originally had everything running with one nameserver on one IP address before switching to cloudflare. Once I switched to CloudFlare, I was able to have two CloudFlare Nameservers. But Now I can't seem to get any nameserver working correctly without using CloudFlare DNS.
Let me preface by saying that I'm not super-well versed in the intricacies of setting up servers, firewalls, and DNS from scratch (though I'm no stranger to the command-line).
Before anyone asks, I did wait an appropriate length of time (where applicable) at each step to allow for DNS propagation.
I first had trouble when trying to add a second IP Address within GCP to my VM instance. I did finally somewhat succeed when I followed this guide. Everything worked at each step along the way, but when testing at the end of the instructions I found that the server didn't respond. I tried to correct the situation by  setting up an additional Google firewall rule as I had for the initial Hestia CP installation. It didn't help (though I'm unsure if I did it correctly so that it would apply to the new IP address).
I then went back within NameCheap's advanced DNS section for my domain and added both Google IP Addresses as ns1 and ns2. I then set them as the custom nameservers in the main domain section but when I tested them online with MXtoolbox or dnschecker they didn't respond either.
I then tried to switch back to the original pre-Cloudflare single nameserver but that didn't work.
It currently appears that I'm stuck with CloudFlare so I'm temporarily re-enabling CloudFlare to get everything live again, but scratching my head on how to proceed. I'm considering starting over at the beginning.
